# Quantlib in JavaScript?

Tags: quantlib

Is there such a thing? Or is there a project around that aims to realize Quantlib in JS? I'm a JS coder and I'd like to get involved if so.

Maybe it seems futile or insane today, but who can doubt that's merely a calendrical issue?

I find no JS R but there's a JStat package that's advertised as "like R:" [**Jstat**](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/03/jstat-its-like-r-for-javascript.php)

To make myself clear, I am looking for a way to run Quantlib on a web client.

Anything happening along these lines?
Thanks!

Comment: We decided to ban questions on specific languages. You should try other SE site like [SO](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Sure, well understood. The question is about implementing Quantlib. Please don't move this question yet, though. If I don't see something in a day or two, I'll delete it.

Comment: Some questions scare me.

Comment: @Brian B -- Heh! I'm a programmer, so to me every problem is merely a matter of a few lines of code :-)

Comment: hello, there's [quantlib.js](https://quantlib.js.org/docs) now

Answer (score 4):

The formally supported way of adding extensions to [QuantLib](http://www.quantlib.org) is by means of the [Swig](http://www.swig.org) extension 'system' / library / tool.

And the [Swig site's page on compatibility](http://www.swig.org/compat.html) has this to about Javascript:

> There is also [SwigJS](http://www.ultravioletconsulting.com/projects/swigjs), a JavaScript module for SWIG

so you could to familiarize yourself with a) how Swig works in the context of QuantLib and b) if/how you can get SwigJS to help you here.

Comment: thanks for your thoughtful answer! Just for everybody's information, the SwigJS link you gave isn't a useful one any more. Further, SWIG is a package that must run on the server. I am looking for Quantlib on the client side. I should have made that clear in my question. Thank you again.

Comment: Swig doesn't know server or client---it creates language bindings. How you deploy is up to you.  And you can hardly have QuantLib *in the client* as the software once compiled is **huge**.  So you probably need a connector of some sort to talk to a computer server which may have QuantLib for you. Somewhat harder.

Comment: Yes, compiled Quantlib must be huge. Still, the client is the future: only a question of time.

Comment: And the answser is -- a *browser extension!* No, no just kidding :-) You imply that my server-side CGI could act as a connector and I'm exploring that. As you say, though, "somewhat harder :-)" Still, I've proved that such a scheme would definitely work, and not just in theory.It's the practice that's daunting. But it might be the best/only way. We can imagine the user preparing Python code on the client and shipping it via my CGI to SWIG on the server. Thank you again.

Comment: Anyone used this in prod with JS?